# jQuery find selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple image switcher in my site with the following structure:

**HTML**

```
<div id="modal">
    <div id="colors">
        <ul class="product-image-thumbs">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                   <img src="thumb-0.jpg" id="thumb-0" class="gallery-image">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="thumb-1.jpg" id="thumb-1" class="gallery-image">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="thumb-2.jpg" id="thumb-2" class="gallery-image">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="photo">
        <img src="current_img" id="1">
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".gallery-image").click(function(){
      $(".photo > img").prop("src", jQuery(this).prop("src"));
   });
});
```

I thought it worked fine until I saw it changed al the img scources that are displayed inside a div with the photo class.

The case is that in the product listing on my webshop al the products have their own div, so the selector appears multiple times on the site.

I've tried the following things

```
jQuery(this).next(".photo > img").prop("src", jQuery(this).prop("src"));
jQuery(this).find(".photo > img").prop("src", jQuery(this).prop("src"));
```

But neither worked, because it couldn't find the element

Comment: What exactly does jQuery(this) refer to?

Comment: `$(this).closest('ul').parent().parent().next('div').find('img').prop("src", $(this).prop("src"));` inside click event handler. Looks very weird, but should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to find image parent `<div>` using `.closest()`, then its next `<div class="photo">` sibling using `.next()` and then `<img>` inside the sibling using `.find()`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pvmv9cf/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".gallery-image").click(function()
    {
        var photoDiv = $(this).closest('ul').parent().next('div.photo');
        photoDiv.find('img').prop("src", $(this).prop("src"));
    });
});
```

**Note**: this code is very sensitive to HTML structure. If, for example `<div id="modal">` will be `<div class="modal">` in all `<div>`s, then it will be shorter and safer with:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".gallery-image").click(function()
    {
        var photoDiv = $(this).closest('.modal').find('.photo');
        photoDiv.find('img').prop("src", $(this).prop("src"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently trying to find the `.photo > img` inside the `.gallery-image`, thus there's no match.

You'd rather select your element directly like this : `$('.photo > img')`.

Example :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".gallery-image").click(function(){

     $('.photo > img').prop("src", $(this).prop("src"));
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modal">
    <div id="colors">
        <ul class="product-image-thumbs">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                   <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" id="thumb-0" class="gallery-image">
                </a>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#">
                 <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" id="thumb-1" class="gallery-image">
             </a>
         </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" id="thumb-2" class="gallery-image">
              </a>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>

<div class="photo">
    <img src="current_img" id="1">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this isn't what I was looking for. As stated in the question I had the code for switching the images. But even with your answer all the divs with the .photo class are getting changed, But I only want to change the source from the current element

Comment: Yes, each product has a number of images. And all are displayed in the same model with the same classes

Comment: @Regent yes i've tried your solution but it didnt work, still couldn't find the element

Comment: @user3164891 it turns out that I made mistake because your HTML has incorrect indents. Since `<div class="photo">` is **inside** `<div id="modal">`, one `.parent()` is unnecessary. Take a look at [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4pvmv9cf/).

Comment: @user3164891 you're welcome. I'll post it as an answer for question completeness.

Comment: @user3164891 Your question wasn't clear enough about that point. I'm glad to help, but such an information have to be included at the first place!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Html:**

```
<div class="photo">
    <img src="" id="current_img">
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".gallery-image").click(function(){
      $('#current_img').prop("src", jQuery(this).prop("src"));
   });
});
```

Comment: At first I thought this was the solution but I found out that I couldn't switch the other images anymore

Comment: @user3164891 Do you mean, if you try clicking other .gallery-image, the src of the current-img is not changing?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery(this) refers to what you just clicked... so traverse up parents() to the outermost div that surrounds your entire block and then traverse back down to your .photo > img.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".gallery-image").click(function(){
     jQuery(this).parents("#modal").find(".photo > img").prop("src", jQuery(this).prop("src"));
  });
});
```

Comment: You actually have the same mistake as I had. Take a look at HTML code attentively: `<div class="photo">` is _inside_ `<div id="modal">`

Comment: ah, yes. I missed that. Updated my solution.